# Translateing misspelled Spanish

Tags: traducción

Can someone tell me what this misspelled Spanish says?

> vy a impizar ha ablar mel io tamben i nu ti vas a intirar de na

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us where it comes from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it says: "Voy a empezar a hablar mal yo también y no te vas a enterar de nada"

Answer (score 0):

I think it says: "Voy a empezar a hablar mejor también tu no te vas a enterar de nada".

In English i think this a suitable translation:"I´m going to start speaking better, also you are not going to know it".